# An error for converting elements in a list

Tags: python, ipython

I am a iPython beginner and I need some help with my code.
I want to read 6 values from input. They can be integers, floats, complex numbers, strings or lists. 
After reading the values and appending them to a list, I do the following conversion:

- for integers: replace it with the square root inside the list.
- for floats: replace it with the cosine of the number inside the list.
- for complex numbers: replace it with its real part inside the list.
- for strings: turn it to capital letters inside the list.
- for lists: discard the last element.

The program throws the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-1f00b88d82c9>", line 20
    else i is list:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and also it can not store a string value into list. It always stores
.
how should I solve this error?
Here is my code:

```
import math as m
l=[]
i=0
while i<6:
    x=input("Enter some values: ")
    if isinstance(x,str):
        x=int(x)
    l.append(x)
    i=i+1
print l
for i in l:
    if i is str:
        i=s.capitalize(i)
    elif i is int:
        i=m.sqrt(i)
    elif i is float:
        i=m.cos(i)
    elif i is complex:
        i=l.real(i)
    else i is list:
        n=len(l)
        i=remove[n-1]
print l
```

Comment: `else` should be `elif` else, there must be nothing after `else`.

Comment: You are not supposed to use the `is` keyword like this. Think you seriously misunderstood this keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace

```
else i is list:
```

with

```
elif i is list:
```

Since you need to evaluate a condition even in your last case, you need the 'if' functionality, so use `elif`. `else` cannot be followed immediately by a condition, hence the error you saw.
Also, you have error in line

```
i=remove[n-1]
```

If you want remove last element from list `i` you need

```
del i[-1]
```